# Html components not loading properly due to timeout in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am hanging on a big problem web components timeout problem.. I am trying to load different JSP in a single attempt. for loading the JSP i am using different timeouts. some time page is loading fine sometime page controls are not loading. any permanent solution is there to fix these type problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this is my code

var delay = 3500;

```
//if (womsKeyid.length>2 && type!='NOTI'){
    if (womsKeyid.length>2 && type!='NOTI'){
    delay = 3500;
    setTimeout(function() {     
        jQuery("#wo_menu_2").trigger("click");  
    },50);


    setTimeout(function() {     
        jQuery("#wo_menu_3").trigger("click");  
    },350);


    /*setTimeout(function() {   
        jQuery("#wo_menu_6").trigger("click");  
    },550);*/


    setTimeout(function() {     
        jQuery("#wo_menu_8").trigger("click");  
    },650);

    setTimeout(function() {     
        jQuery("#wo_menu_9").trigger("click");  
    },800);

    setTimeout(function() { 
        //alert(1);
        jQuery("#wo_menu_0").trigger("click");
        jQuery('#frmWorkOrder').css('display','block');
        jQuery('#hdnFirstLoad').val("0");

    },2500);

}
/* else {
    jQuery('#frmWorkOrder').css('display','block');
    jQuery("#wo_menu_0").trigger("click");
    jQuery('#hdnFirstLoad').val("0");
} */
else{
    delay = 3500;
    setTimeout(function() {     
        jQuery("#wo_menu_2").trigger("click");  
    },50);


    setTimeout(function() {     
        jQuery("#wo_menu_3").trigger("click");  
    },350);


    /* setTimeout(function() {  
        jQuery("#wo_menu_6").trigger("click");  
    },550);
     */

    setTimeout(function() {     
        jQuery("#wo_menu_5").trigger("click");  
    },650);

    setTimeout(function() {     
        jQuery("#wo_menu_6").trigger("click");  
    },800);

    setTimeout(function() { 
        //alert(1);
        jQuery("#wo_menu_0").trigger("click");
        jQuery('#frmWorkOrder').css('display','block');
        jQuery('#hdnFirstLoad').val("0");

    },2500);

}

}
setTimeout(function() {

    fnDisableWorkFlowFields();

    //alert(type);
    if (type=='NOTI'){
        //jQuery('#showFunLocn').css('display','none');
        jQuery("#lblNotifntype").addClass('mandatory-lbl'); 
        jQuery("#lblSapwotype").removeClass('mandatory-lbl');
        jQuery("#lblTradeid").removeClass('mandatory-lbl');

        clearField("cmbWomsSaporderType");
        enableFields("cmbWomsSapnotfnType");
        disableField("frmWorkOrder","cmbWomsSaporderType");
        disableField("frmWorkOrder","chkInternalType");
        disableField("frmWorkOrder","chkExtRepairType");
        jQuery(' input[id="chbExtServiceType"]').attr('disabled',true);
        jQuery("#lblSapNotifn").css("padding-left","86px");
        jQuery("#lblWoProblem").html("Notification Text");
        jQuery("#lblPerfexNo").html("Perfex Notifn.No.");
        jQuery("#divCntrlKey").css('display','none');
    }
    else{
        jQuery("#lblSapwotype").addClass('mandatory-lbl');
        jQuery("#lblTradeid").addClass('mandatory-lbl');    
        jQuery("#lblNotifntype").removeClass('mandatory-lbl');

        clearField("cmbWomsSapnotfnType");
        disableField("frmWorkOrder","cmbWomsSapnotfnType"); 
        //enableFields("cmbWomsSapnotfnType");
        enableFields("cmbWomsSaporderType");
        jQuery("#lblSapNotifn").css("padding-left","6px");
        jQuery("#lblWoProblem").html("Order Text");
        jQuery("#lblPerfexNo").html("Perfex Order.No.");
        jQuery("#divCntrlKey").css('display','block');
    }
},delay);
```